# getItem, data and getItemCount in Vritualised list

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I wanted to use react virtualised list but for some reason I wasn't able to make sense out from their docs.

Link to their docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist

So consider this as my data type

```
export interface Review {
  id: number
  product: string;
  helpful_count: string;
  total_comments: number;
  url: string;
  review_country: string;
  reviewed_at: string;
  review_text: string;
  review_rating: string;
  product_company: string;
  profile_name: string;
  review_title: string;
}

export type Reviews = Array<Review>;
```

And this as a component/code snippet

```
interface Item {
  review: Review
}

const Item = ({ review }: Item) => {
  return (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{review.profile_name}</Text>
  </View>
)};

const Landing = ({ reviews }: Props) => {
  const data:Reviews  = reviews.data || []
  const getDataCount = () => data.length
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <VirtualizedList
        data={data}
        initialNumToRender={4}
        renderItem={(review:any) => <Item review={review} />}
        keyExtractor={(review, index)  => `${index}`}
        getItemCount={getDataCount}
        getItem={getItem}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Now my data does not have shape `{key: string}` (from types). Can someone tell me in that case what I need to in getItem and also does it make sense to use `const getDataCount = () => data.length` like this?

Answer (score 0):

i took the code from [react native virtualized list](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist) and modified a bit

```
const DATA = [
  {
    name : `john doe`,
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name : `john ree`,
    age: 24
  },
  {
    name : `john wefw`,
    age: 25
  }
];

const getItem = (data, index) => {
  
  return ({
  id: Math.random().toString(12).substring(0),
  title: `Item ${index+1} ${data[index].name} ${data[index].age}`
})
};

const getItemCount = (data) => DATA.length

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <VirtualizedList
        data={DATA}
        initialNumToRender={4}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.key}
        getItemCount={getItemCount}
        getItem={getItem}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

and the output is

Item 1 john doe 23  Item 2 john ree 24 Item 3 john wefw 25

so you can get a number like data[index]."number".
and you can use DATA.length if only you have some elements in your array already